# Does clear application cached also reset application settings?

Tags: android

I tried clearing my app cached and open my app again.
but the permission does not reset.
so my question is can clearing app cached also reset app permissions?

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by "clearing my app cached". Are you talking about the "clear cache" feature in the AndroidStudio development environment, then no, that does not alter any permissions, or about the apps data cache in the android device, then that does also not modify any permissions and is off-topic here, since this is a place offering help with _programming related questions_.

Answer (score 0):

No! You need to clear storage for the permissions to reset.

Quoting from [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5744208/6611700):

> The cache is basically a *temporary storage* area for an application while it's running -- it can store things like temporary images downloaded from the internet. Clearing it shouldn't really have much of an effect from a user perspective. Clearing the data, however, **will remove any user data, databases, etc** -- this includes things like account settings, persistent preferences, etc. Clearing the data should revert the application back to it's state as it was when you first installed it.